# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем привет! Кто знает, как я могу решить эту ошибку?

profile:1269 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
at response (profile:1269:30)
at XMLHttpRequest. (profile:1230:5)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_send(data, element){


    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    

    ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){

        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

            response(ajax.responseText,element);
        }

    });

    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    ajax.open("post","<?=ROOT?>ajax.php",true);
    ajax.send(data);

}

function response(result,element){


    if(result != ""){

        // console.log(result);

        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        
        //console.log(obj); 

        if(typeof obj.action != 'undefined'){

            if(obj.action == 'like_post'){

                var likes = "";
                
                if(typeof obj.likes != 'undefined'){
                    likes = (parseInt(obj.likes) > 0) ? "Like(" +obj.likes+ ")" : "Like" ;
                    element.innerHTML = likes;
                }

                if(typeof obj.info != 'undefined'){
                    var info_element = document.getElementById(obj.id);
                
                    info_element.innerHTML = obj.info;
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
    function like_post(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var link = e.target.href;

    var data = {};
    data.link = link;
    data.action = "like_post";
    //console.log(data)
    ajax_send(data,e.target);

    }
```

1. info_element.innerHTML = obj.info;
2. response(ajax.responseText,element);

Comment: `document.getElementById(obj.id);` - очевидно вернул `null`, а значит искомого элемента нет на странице